# how to set absolute position div

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a absolute position div that I set on the below of another div. When I maximize or minimize browser press ctrl +/- then my absolute position div don’t stay his original position.  Please can someone point out what I may be doing wrong here? Many thanks. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            #header
            {
                width: 980px;
                height:80px;
                background: #006666;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #content
            {
                color: white;
                padding-top: 30px;
                margin-left: 200px;
            }

            #menu
            {
                position: absolute;
                top:50px;
                left:222px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 20px;
                background: red;
            }                
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="content">Uttara.hr</div>
            <div id="menu"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what do you actually want. Please be more specific in your question

Comment: Which <div> do you want to be fixed? I can see two divs on your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is the red `div` below your text, so you need to give `position: relative;` to the parent div so that absolute positioned div doesn't flow out in the wild

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kV7Rh/)

(Note: you can now adjust the div the way you want)

CSS

```
#header {
    width: 980px;
    height:80px;
    background: #006666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; <---------Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set `#header`  to either absolute or relative positioning to keep the contents of its children inside it.

or you can make both `#content` and `#menu` positioned absolute, then they'll move around together as the screen adjusts

Answer (score 0):

Select css for your out-most div and set its position relative, then set all the positions for all your divs.

For your out-most div:

```
style="position: relative;"
```